# REST API Design: Should the update (PUT) request include the ID in the resource URL?

Tags: rest, api-design, url

When designing a REST API for update request. Usually PUT is used. **Question: should the resource URL include the id usually?**

For instance, there is a *book* resource: `http://localhost:8080/library/book`
When updating a given book with Id, say `123`, we could send a PUT request with JSON as the HTTP request *body* as the update resource. The URL can include the id of the book, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/library/book/123` But is this OK? or should we always avoid giving the id in the URL for update request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When designing a REST API for update request. Usually PUT is used. Question: should the resource URL include the id usually?

The target URI of the PUT request should match the target URI of the GET request used to retrieve a representation of the same resource.

```
GET /a86e4776-699e-428a-b1a8-5c2828910d86
```

```
200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

Helo World
```

```
PUT /a86e4776-699e-428a-b1a8-5c2828910d86
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello World
```

Therefore, including an "id" in the URI for a PUT request follows precisely the same rules as including an "id" in the URI for a GET request.

The same is true, of course, for POST, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, etc.  The resource identifier identifies the resource.

Now, you local spelling conventions may say that resource identifiers can include identifiers, or not, or only obfuscated identifiers, or whatever.  Those kinds of design decisions are local to you, and will be motivated by the kinds of things that are most important to you (ex: we want to make things easy for the operators who need to read our access logs).

---

Reviewing [Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) may help clarify

> HTTP is an application protocol, whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network.

Comment: sounds like you disagree with amon about POST?

Comment: Really? what part?

Comment: "The same is true, of course, for POST, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, etc. The resource identifier identifies the resource."

Comment: I think amon and I are in complete agreement on that point.  We might disagree about which resource in your resource model should handle a POST request (there are trade offs) but I'm sure we understand target URI the same way.  If you think that's still unclear, it might make sense to pose it as a question....

Answer (score 4):

An URI identifies a resource. A PUT request is supposed to *create or replace* the representation of that resource. So, if you want to replace the state of book `123`, you should `PUT /book/123`. Think of `PUT` as *uploading* an entire file, but you have to give the target “filename”. There is a strong expectation that if you do a `PUT /url` and later `GET /url`, you'd get back an equivalent representation to what you've uploaded. This indicates that `PUT /book` would be incorrect since a later `GET /book` probably wouldn't return the data you've just uploaded about book 123.

If you want to perform a *partial update* of a book's state, use a `PATCH` request. This too would generally require the resource's ID in the URI.

If you want the endpoint to perform some other action, consider a `POST` request. For example `POST /book` might use the body of the request to figure out which resources should be affected. If you're not sure which HTTP request method to use but if you want the server to *do something* (possibly with side effects), then `POST` is a good default. `POST` is most commonly used for form submissions, but it's also often used for creating new resources if the server should assign the ID.

Recommended further reading: [*HTTP request methods* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and [*Request Methods* in RFC 7231](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#methods).

Comment: In general I agree with all of these points, although in practice I usually just use PUT for all updates (full or partial). Callers don't really care about the distinction between PUT and PATCH - they just want to update the data.

Answer (score -3):

No.

If you are updating resource you will be sending the whole resource in the body, and this will include the Id.

So sending it twice is unnecessary at best and introduces an error (if there is a mismatch) at worst.

Amon and Voice of Unreason, object that the URI = the resource that the put must replace. But I would argue that this is an overly strict interpretation, which is only applicable where the id *is* the filename.

After all, in such a case you would have to replace book 1 with book 2 if you sent id 2 in the content. Also the equivalent POST documentation insists the only difference is the idempotency of the request, but is happy to have a single url for different documents.

Say you programmed both solutions. The strict interpretation would require a check that both ids matched, whereas my practical interpretation would not. My solution would use less electricity and be faster, cheaper to run and throw less errors.

Comment: For a POST request, I'd agree. But for a PUT request, your recommendations violate the semantics of this request type.

Comment: link to spec where it says that?

Comment: I think this is given by [section 4.3.4 of RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4): “The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.” The “target resource” is identified by the request URI (compare section 2), not by the payload contents.

Comment: seems like there is a handy get out clause "A PUT request applied to the target resource can have side effects on  other resources."

Comment: The point we disagree on is how the resource is identified – I and the standard use the URL for this, you propose that the request body should participate in resource identification. I think we both can agree that the request might have side effects. For example, PUTting a new book might change the list of books in the author's resource.

Comment: no. i agree with you that the URI is the resource meant by the spec. I guess im trying to squeeze through updating a different resource "books" with the side effect of changing "book/1"